# Atribuir retorno de função a uma variável usando angularjs $promise

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um angular.*factory* que retorna dados de *json*. Dentro de um *controller* invoco o mesmo para pegar os dados, a questão é que ao invocar o mesmo dentro do *controller* o *objeto* existe apenas se usar um `console.log`, se mandar atribuir para uma variável a mesma fica vazia. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
//Factory
app.factory('dataLoad', function($http, $q) {
     return {
         getContent: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get('data-json.php')
            .success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

### Controller:

```
$scope.node = [];

dataLoad.getContent().then(
    function(data) {
        //Objeto é impresso normalmente
        console.log(data);

        //nulo
        $scope.node = data;
    }
);

console.log($scope.node);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é o seguinte, o seu **getContent** é uma função assíncrona, então quando você faz o **console.log($scope.node)** o *promise* ainda não estava resolvido.

Quando alguma atribuição for feita dentro de um promise ela nunca estará disponível imediatamente mas somente quando o promise for resolvido.

Tente utilizar um **$watch** para testar e ver o que acontece.

EX:

```
$scope.node = [];

dataLoad.getContent().then(
  function(data) {
      //Objeto é impresso normalmente
      console.log(data);

      //nulo
      $scope.node = data;
  }
);
$scope.$watch('node', function(new_value, old_value){
  console.log($scope.node, new_value, old_value);
})
```

Comment: Usei o $watch e os dados agora estão presentes. No caso sempre terei que usar watch para pegar os dados?

Comment: Se você mandar imprimir na view **{{node}}** ele vai funcionar sem o **$watch** porque o angular faz um **bind** dessa propriedade, a questão é que o **console.log** é executado antes do promise ser resolvido. O que você precisa fazer realmente?

Comment: Daniel, preciso atribuir o retorno para uma variavel, pois irei chamar o factory N vezes e com o retorno irei chamar outro método para exibir os dados.

Comment: Acredito que o correto então seria chamar o seu método dentro do **.then** em vez de atribuir a uma variável para depois chamar o método.

Comment: Valeu Daniel. Assunto resolvido com o código que mandou.